# Advantage of exporting as object in module export/import system

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

There are several ways of using module system, I'm just curious, what is the advantage of storing the functions as variable then export it as object in the end?

Like

```
const getUsers = user => request(`https://api.github.com/users`)
const getUser = user => request(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
const saveUser = id => request(`https://api.github.com/user/${id}`)

export { getUsers, getUser, saveUser }
```

I can simply do this,

```
export getUsers(user) => request(`https://api.github.com/users`)
export getUser(user) => request(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
export saveUser(id) => request(`https://api.github.com/user/${id}`)
```

The usage is the same, says the file name is githubApi.js

I do `import { getUsers } from './githubApi'`

Answer (score 2):

Generally just readability. If you have exported functions defined all through a file it can be easier to see what's been exported when they're grouped together at the bottom.

I usually export at the point of declaration unless the file is getting too long/complex to keep track

Comment: I think it's subjective, I see export I can straight away get what's been export, you saved one line and lots of duplication.

Comment: Yep, readability is 100% subjective. Because there is no functional difference, there is no non-subjective answer to this question